# How to use SQL Server apply in typeorm

Tags: sql-server, typescript, typeorm, outer-apply

For a project I'm assigned to I have to alter a typeorm querybuilder to incorporate an "outer apply".

I could not find any support in typeorm for this.

I've looked for ways to do this by a join and a sub-query in the "on" of the join but the amount off data in the DB generates a timeout using multiple sub-queries.
Furthermore, I looked into inserting a RAW query into the builder but could not find the mechanism for this.

Is there any way to use "apply" with typeorm?

I personally prefer to write all my queries by hand so if you come up with reasons NOT to use typeorm, I agree!! But this is an existing project and no way I'm going to rewrite it!

Comment: I have no familiarity with  TypeORM, but a quick search found this [GitHub](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5402) issue, which suggests it isn't supported, however, demonstrates a work around too.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried but since the complexity of the outer apply in combination with the subquery needed to apply it got into a timeout of more than 60 seconds

Comment: This is my personal opinion. But I feel like at a certain point, an ORM is not going to suit your needs, especially when it comes to query tuning. You may want to consider building this directly in SQL as a function/stored procedure/view (which ever fits best) in order to allow for proper query/index tuning. ORM's are great, but usually for operations that don't require tuning.